# can't assign onclick event inside a custom dojo widget

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, onclick

I have a custom widget, defined similar to this:

```
dojo.declare('myWidget', [dijit._WidgetBase, dijit._Templated],
{
    'templateString':'<span>' +
            '<a  dojoAttachPoint="linkNode" href="blah.php">' +
                '<img class="thumbNail" src="blahthumb.php" />' +
            '</a>' +
            '<h4 dojoAttachPoint="title" class="title">${blahtitle}</h4>' +
        '</span>',
    'stuff':null,
    'startup':function()
    {
        dojo.connect(this.linkNode, 'onclick', function(e){dojo.stopEvent(e);alert('hi');});
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to assign an onclick event on a portion of the custom widget. I'm creating the widget programmatically, and pushing it onto the page similar to this:

```
...
    f = new myWidget(stuff);
    f.startup();    
    li = dojo.create('li', {'class':'thingy'});
    dojo.place(f.domNode, li);
    dojo.place(li, this.gallery); // within another widget,
...
```

Unfortunately the onclick event being connected in the startup method, isn't firing. I've tried to assign it various ways, nothing seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It wasn't related to how I built the widget so much, as a function I was running that would modify the widget immediately after it ran. Not sure WHY it caused the onclick events to disappear, but it was modifying the innerHTML property of some of the widgets' dom nodes. When I comment out that section, everything works splendidly.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure why your case is not working, maybe it is because you do not propagate the method call to startup by adding `this.inherited(arguments);` to the end of the method.

However, in your case I think another approach might be more suitable. In addition to the functionality around `dojoAttachPoint` which you obviously know about, dojo also has `dojoAttachEvent`. I would suggest that you do it something like this instead:

```
dojo.declare('myWidget', [dijit._WidgetBase, dijit._Templated],
{
    'templateString':
        '<span>' +
            '<a dojoAttachEvent="onClick:_linkNodeClick" href="blah.php">' +
                '<img class="thumbNail" src="blahthumb.php" />' +
            '</a>' +
            '<h4 dojoAttachPoint="title" class="title">${blahtitle}</h4>' +
        '</span>',

    'stuff':null,

    '_linkNodeClick':function(e){
        dojo.stopEvent(e);
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

### Edit

Okey, I tried it myself now and managed to get it working like this:

```
dojo.provide("MyWidget");
dojo.declare('MyWidget', [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],
{
    'templateString':
        '<span>' +
            '<a dojoAttachPoint="linkNode">' +
                '<img class="thumbNail" src="blahthumb.php" />' +
            '</a>' +
            '<h4 dojoAttachPoint="title" class="title">${blahtitle}</h4>' +
        '</span>',

    'startup':function()
    {
        dojo.connect(this.linkNode, 'onclick', function(e){dojo.stopEvent(e);alert('hi');});
    }
});
```

And the nto start it, I had to attach it to DOM before calling startup.

```
var f = new MyWidget();
dojo.body().appendChild(f.domNode);
f.startup();
```

The only thing I modified from your original was to add dojo.provide(...) and I don't know if that was actually the important thing. Then I used _Widget instead of _WidgetBase. And then also change the order like I mentioned. Now, when I click the image it alerts "hi" and then the link is not followed.

Comment: Hadn't tried that method of adding an event. Alas, it's still not working. I'm beginning to think it's somewhere else within the dojo rendering steps I've somehow modified improperly and is failing to carry over events. I've been able to assign the event after the page rendered via the firebug console.

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that you call startup() on the widget before you have added it to the DOM. Try changing that order and see if it works.

Comment: And another thing, is there a special reason why you are inheriting from _WidgetBase? Cause I think the ususal way is to inherit from _Widget which in turn inherits from _WidgetBase and a bunch of other modules.

Comment: I tried flipping the order, no effect. And I thought I read somewhere that _Widget was deprecated in turn for _WidgetBase... I could be wrong, I'll try switching it.

Comment: Managed to get it working for myself at least. See my edited answer.

Comment: I don't think doing a dojo.provide would make any difference. Changing widgetBase to Widget might be the deal though.

Comment: I tried switching, and still didn't work. I've made custom widgets with WidgetBase quite a few times before, without issue. I think the problem may be located in a section of code I left out of the example, I've been unable to narrow down the failure point though. You're example has worked for me before as I've set things up like that in several other cases. It's just not working this time... :(

Comment: FYI, you may want to reference this ( [dojo toolkit _Widget](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/_Widget.html) ) in regards to _WidgetBase vs. _Widget

Comment: I finally figured it out. It wasn't related to how I built the widget so much, as a function I was running that would modify the widget immediately after it ran. Not sure WHY it caused the onclick events to disappear, but it was modifying the innerHTML property of some of the dom nodes. When I comment out that section, everything works splendidly.